# Help with format string in scanf

Tags: c

Here's the statement:

```
int i;
scanf("%d ",&i);
```

Why does the space at the end of the format string causes scanf to accept two inputs instead of 1?

Comment: What do you mean "accepts two inputs"?  What does your input look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The space at the end of the format string tells scanf to eat whitespace after the first integer.  It's not actually accepting a second input.  When you do enter a second value, scanf sees that the whitespace is finished it returns, storing the first integer into your variable i.  The "second input" is still in the standard input stream.

Comment: What do you mean by eat the whitespace after the first integer? Eat the white space in the stdin buffer? When do I need to eat the whitespace. Please give an example.

Comment: You don't **have** to eat the whitespace.  You are instructing scanf to eat any whitespace after it reads the integer.  Until scanf sees either an EOF or something other than whitespace, it can't return.